# Hiding Birt columns dynamically

Tags: java, sql, oracle, birt, crosstab

I am trying to display the no of players and best players statistics in a country for specific games in a report

[image]

Need to modify the cross tab to show only statistics of the football.How to hide the cross tab column when name of the game(column) is  "cricket".
I don't want to achieve this using filters in data sets or by adding condition in where clause of the query.

Comment: As you guess, the most efficient way would be to filter in the dataset query. Alternatively, just adding a crosstab filter would do the trick, see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28210862/how-to-slice-a-data-cube-in-birt-designer/28260846#28260846)

Comment: facing same issue. I want to achieve the same. Let me know if you have solution